# Can the asparagus fern (Asparagus sprengeri) regrow from the bulbs/root nodes that were underground?

Tags: asparagus

My asparagus fern has died due to lack of water (that is, I forgot about it). When I was eliminating it I found glassy bulbs in the soil:

[image]

I was wondering if these can be revived if I put them in wet soil until they have enough water to start growing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this plant can be revived.  Just plant them in soil, water and wait.  Do not overwater!  With very  few roots the plant cannot take up much water.  Only water when the top inch of the soil is dry.

A position in good light will help too

Comment: Should the part that originally had the leaves be poking out?

Comment: Everything in the picture goes beneath the soil. Any parts that were green go above